# Delete child documents without parent in Elasticsearch using Jest

Tags: java, scala, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api, elasticsearch-jest

As the title says, I'm trying to delete all the parentless child documents using Jest. If I got things correctly, I need to use DeleteByQuery, and my proposed solution is this:

```
val allParentlessChildren = QueryBuilders
    .boolQuery()
    .mustNot(JoinQueryBuilders.hasParentQuery(
      "my_parent",
      QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery(),
      false)
    )
val delete = new DeleteByQuery.Builder(allParentlessChildren.toString)
    .addIndex("my_index")
    .addType("my_child")
    .build()
```

However, I get `routing_missing_exception`. [Investigating online](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/docs-delete.html#delete-parent), it seems I need to set parent type for routing, however, apart from specifying it in `hasParentQuery` idk where else I need to add it?

Although I found [some examples](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/deleting-a-parent-document-with-no-child-documents/17690) how to do it with REST API, I wasn't able to find ones that use Jest, so hopefully someone can help out.

I'm using Elasticsearch 5.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just needed to add routing, however, in Jest it seems it's slightly hidden in the `setParameter` method:

```
val delete = new DeleteByQuery.Builder(allParentlessChildren.toString)
    .addIndex("my_index")
    .addType("my_child")
    .setParameter(Parameters.ROUTING, "my_parent") // <-- added line
    .build()
```